# How to recode many data frame columns with same function

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have a data frame like this:

```
CriterionVar Var1 Var2 Var3
3            0    0    0
1            0    0    0
2            0    0    0
5            0    0    0
```

I want to recode the values of `Var1`, `Var2`, and `Var3` based on the value of `CriterionVar`. In pseudocode, it would be something like this:

```
for each row
   if (CriterionVar.value >= Var1.index) Var1 = 1
   if (CriterionVar.value >= Var2.index) Var2 = 1
   if (CriterionVar.value >= Var3.index) Var3 = 1
```

The recoded data frame would look like this:

```
CriterionVar Var1 Var2 Var3
3            1    1    1
1            1    0    0
2            1    1    0
5            1    1    1
```

Obviously, that is not the way to get it done because (1) the number of `VarN` columns is determined by a data value, and (2) it's just ugly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes. edited. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more general values of CriterionVar, you can use `outer` to construct a logical matrix which you can use for indexing like this:

```
dat[2:4][outer(dat$CriterionVar, seq_along(names(dat)[-1]), ">=")] <- 1
```

In this example, this returns

```
dat
  CriterionVar Var1 Var2 Var3
1            3    1    1    1
2            1    1    0    0
3            2    1    1    0
4            5    1    1    1
```

---

A second method using `col`, which returns a matrix of the column index, is a tad bit more direct:

```
dat[2:4][dat$CriterionVar >= col(dat[-1])] <- 1
```

and returns the desired result.

---

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(CriterionVar = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 5L), Var1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), .Names = c("CriterionVar", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df[,-1] = lapply(2:NCOL(df), function(i) as.numeric(df[,1] >= (i-1)))
df
#  CriterionVar Var1 Var2 Var3
#1            3    1    1    1
#2            1    1    0    0
#3            2    1    1    0
#4            5    1    1    1
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(CriterionVar = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 5L), Var1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1), Var2 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), Var3 = c(1, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("CriterionVar", 
"Var1", "Var2", "Var3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I wonder If `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(i)...)` idiom can be used here to simply update the existing df and thus avoid the whole `setNames`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big proponent of `vapply`: it's fast, and you know the shape of what it'll return. The only problem is the resulting matrix is usually the "sideways" version of what you want. But `t()` fixes that easily enough.

```
n_var_cols <- 3
truncated_criterion <- pmin(dat[["CriterionVar"]], n_var_cols)
row_template <- rep_len(0, n_var_cols)

replace_up_to_index <- function(index) {
  replace(row_template, seq_len(index), 1)
}

over_matrix <- vapply(
  X         = truncated_criterion,
  FUN       = replace_up_to_index,
  FUN.VALUE = row_template
)
over_matrix <- t(over_matrix)

dat[, -1] <- over_matrix
dat
#   CriterionVar Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1            3    1    1    1
# 2            1    1    0    0
# 3            2    1    1    0
# 4            5    1    1    1
```

There was some bookkeeping in the first three lines, but nothing too bad. I used `pmin()` to restrict the criteria values to be no greater than the number of `VarN` columns.